# mongoose aggregate and remove field if condition met

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a data model which occasionally has empty arrays. I'd like to return a query that removes the empty arrays. Here's what I have so far:

```
var query = Recipe.aggregate([
    { $match: {'sites': site}},
     { $project:{ 
        '_id':0,
        'data.coupons': 
          {
            $cond: {if:{ $exists: true, $not: {$size: 0} }, then:1, else:0} 
          } 
      }}
]);
```

Currently I'm returning the error `MongoError: exception: invalid operator '$exists'`. Is there another way to check for empty arrays? I'd like to keep the value if it meets the condition and reject it if it does not.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33045045/edit) your question to add sample document with expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
$cond: {if:{ $not: {$size: 0} }, then:1, else:0}
```